# How to use async Django views without sleep?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm working on a Django view where I have two time-consuming operations that could be run in parallel (reads from a remote DB). I have created an async view but, presumably because I have no `sleep` statements, my code is still executing sequentially. If I understand correctly, Python code will always be executed sequentially until it finds some statement that allows it to pause and go execute the other task. I understand that `sleep` is one of these statements, but what are the others? The documentation and every single tutorial I found uses `sleep` statements in literally ALL of their examples. It almost seems like the only way to make code run async is to use a `sleep` statement, but that seems weird because `sleep` makes my code pause and do nothing, which can't be suitable for production.

Here's some code that runs asynchronously:

```
import time
import asyncio

from django.http import HttpResponse


async def func1(n):
    print("Running func1...")
    for i in range(n):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Done with func1!")
    return n


async def func2(n):
    print("Running func2...")
    for i in range(n):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Done with func2!")
    return n


async def myview(request):
    print("Running myview...")
    start = time.time()
    res1, res2 = await asyncio.gather(func1(3), func2(4))
    duration = time.time() - start
    return HttpResponse(f"Duration: {duration}.")
```

Output:

```
Running myview...
Running func1...
Running func2...
Done with func1!
Done with func2!
```

And some that doesn't:

```
import time
import asyncio

from django.http import HttpResponse


@sync_to_async
def func1(ids):
    print("Running func1...")
    result = operation1(ids)
    print("Done with func1!")
    return result


@sync_to_async
def func2(ids):
    print("Running func2...")
    result = operation2(ids)
    print("Done with func2!")
    return result


async def myview(request):
    print("Running myview...")
    start = time.time()
    res1, res2 = await asyncio.gather(func1([25905]), func2([25905]))
    print("Result 1:\n", res1)
    print("Result 2:\n", res2)
    duration = time.time() - start
    return HttpResponse(f"Duration: {duration}.")
```

Output:

```
Running myview...
Running func1...
Done with func1!
Running func2...
Done with func2!
Result 1:
 <coroutine object SyncToAsync.__call__ at 0x7ff173d5d050>
Result 2:
 <coroutine object SyncToAsync.__call__ at 0x7ff1746264d0>
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:1787: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SyncToAsync.__call__' was never awaited
  handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

My guess is that my understanding of how this whole thing works is flawed in some fundamental way. What am I missing?

Comment: You can use `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to yield control to another coroutine but not actually sleep

Comment: You don’t specifically need `asyncio.sleep`, but you do need to await something that will yield back to the event loop. Ideally this is whatever does the slow I/O. You could use an asyncio-aware driver to connect to your external database (that won’t work if you’re using the Django ORM to do it). If `sleep` is the only thing you can await, you’ll be able to switch between the 2 coroutines, but their combined runtime won’t decrease.